# Can a moderator collect and send links to me to deleted answers of mine?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, post-ban

I am responding to the suggestion here:

*[What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)*

Under: **How can I find my deleted posts?**

To:

> ask a support question on Meta for a moderator to provide links to those posts.

This is such a question to moderators on Meta.

I am not an avid user of the Stack Overflow family of sites, but I do find them useful very often for the very reason that questions and answers are indeed returned by many search engines in response to queries I submit when researching something.

I have a modest, but positive, reputation on various sites, but on Stack Overflow itself an answering ban.

I'm happy to try and work out why and to redress that, and appreciate that these are big sites with a lot of automation behind them in this area in particular. But the link the message provides shows me only one answer I submitted:

[cmake not compiling with qt4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26833912/cmake-not-compiling-with-qt4/36371273#36371273)

Which is unfixable in a sense. If there is a criticism here, it is possibly only that the question itself and answer are not of lasting general use, but related to a specific help-style request that runs against the Stack Overflow mission in a sense. Yet deleting my answer won't help me, and I have not control over the question and not even the asker has bothered to return and vote the answer as useful in a sense.

So I'm stuck wondering if there are deleted answers of mine that I can't see and if there is anything I could do with them.

I found out I have an answer ban after typing an answer that I felt would help someone. So in protecting others from time-wasting we waste my time?

On looking at it, the question itself is possibly in the category of help-style questions and not likely one to have future value to the community, so perhaps it's better if I don't answer it. It's an easy one to answer for anyone with modest experience related to the question asked in any how - low fruit so to speak. Hence the appeal.

I scored 2 little reputation points by tidying up the question mind you and am not even sure how that happens. As, if a moderator approved them, the same moderator might conclude the question is worth downvoting on basis of no future value.

In short, I would like to pursue the advice that I read in the post above and request a list of my deleted answers and of course any leverage on removing this answer ban. It seems a little difficult to gain reputation if one can't answer questions.

On the flip side I have some open questions with no responses (frustrating to me), but which might also fall prey to the judgment that they are specific help-like questions with questionable future value. Though of course when I posted I did not feel that and I only post a question after a LOT of on-line research and trying to couch a specific experience into a general context if I can.

If a moderator can help out with a list of deleted answers I'll see if I can gain traction on them.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26866420/will-gobject-idle-addfunction-block-until-executing-the-function-is-finished/39555287#39555287, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39379996/editors-not-found-after-upgrade/39502133#39502133, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490509/variables-not-showing-while-debugging-in-eclipse/36350976#36350976, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571495/eclipsepydev-sluggish-variables-window/36329770#36329770, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543848/does-form-data-still-transfer-if-the-input-tag-has-no-name/25636520#25636520

Comment: Thanks Cody! These are all old (2014-2016) and I'd gladly fix/undo them to improve standing. But out of interest, would an edit to any of those to improve it, and then an undelete for a better effort, have any conceivable positive effect? The salient question is, what positive steps can someone take to amend ...

Comment: I honestly don't know, Bernd, and that's why I didn't post a complete answer. It seems to me like you're in an unfortunate position where you have a handful of old answers from a time when you were unfamiliar with the Stack Overflow model, and that's preventing you from digging yourself out of the hole. I'm not even sure if you'll be able to fix most of those old answers. The only real details I know about the auto-block is what's documented [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583), and you've already read that.

Comment: Thanks Cody! It is unfortunate. It would benefit the sites I think if the possibility of learning be accounted for in such auto-bans and/or the means of escaping them be at least somehow attainable if not publicly posted (for fear of people gaming the system). I mean we all have learning curves. The robotic nature of the ban is concerning as it can't take into account broader reputation components (cross-site for example - more recent interaction I have with other Stack Overflow family sites is much stronger as I've come closer to understanding the model I guess.

Comment: @CodyGray you might be interested in this userscript for easier copy-paste links to deleted Q&As from the question asker on the main site: "[Post Ban Deleted Posts](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/#post-ban-deleted-posts-)" - must be either closed as dupe of or has a comment linking to question https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583, or tagged [post-ban].

Comment: You were not in that deep; I see the ban has already been lifted.

Comment: True! Wow, I wonder how I can tell. The dilemma I face (I wonder if it has a classic name like the Prisoner's Dilemma does?) is that the only way I know to test this is to attempt an answer (which I did earlier today) which is truly helpful. I have reasonable standards for that and do a little research and put some thought into presentation, not least because I do want to contribute positively but also earn a few simple rights. And if I do that and find I'm banned, I've wasted my time. Guess I'm stuck trying again if I find a question that speaks to my skills on my home page.

Comment: I just did a test:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54864015/python-regex-doest-take-all-groups-in-a-match/54864210#54864210

For the fun of it, and it worked. I'm an answer capable contributor once more. And hope I can give back to the community a little of what I have received from it!

Comment: Thanks for the tip! It was just a quick test really, fishing for a question I could answer well with little invested effort, in a hurry. The question is downvoted 3 times indeed and I concur, it's the sort of question I resolve easily with a little research and don't post on a forum really. That's life. Using my regained power to try and tidy up some of the Django m2m validation questions that have collected over the years with a summary of the best solution we've nutted out to date on the Developers list (which is far from stable, complete or official but is working!)

Comment: Remember, if you want to address someone directly in comments (answer a comment) you need to "ping" them using @ and the user name, for example @BerndWechner. Otherwise, people won't know you've reacted to their comment.

Answer (score 9):

I see from the comments that your ban has been lifted, but I want to offer some advice: tread lightly. It's much, much better to have fewer, infrequent high quality posts than it is to have many lower quality ones.

If you're not sure whether something will make a good post or not, err on the side of not posting it. Alternatively, do more research to confirm it. Read other resources (documentation, blogs, etc.), test your ideas, etc. This applies [as much to questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/1394393) as it does to answers. Also look closely at a question *before* answering, to determine whether it's adding useful information to our repository that other people are going to be able to find when they need it.

I can tell you personally that this approach works. I have 320 posts over 6 years and 9 months, which comes out to less than 4 posts per month on average. It's probably even lower if you exclude my first couple of years. I find nowadays that I only post if I happen to come across a question where I know some information I can add *and* it's a good question, if I have a difficult problem that I've been unable to sort out despite lots of reading and trying things, or I figure something out that is poorly documented. I rarely actively seek questions to answer. I don't have a lot of contributions, but I feel good about most of the ones I do have. Not everyone has to be a 100k rep user that answers every third question they see to be a contributing member of the community, and most people won't be. Contribute where you can and should.

Lastly, let me thank you for realizing that SO has a mission: to be a high quality knowledge repository. We need more people who realize that. SO (the company) has been on a rather strong campaign to weaken that mission.

Comment: The **look closely at the _question_ before answering** can't be emphasized enough. Hopefully one should try to see that a question is really fit for the site before deciding to answer, and to flag/vote to close otherwise.

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate the thoughts. All I can say is that one question front I always do as much possible research as I can before asking a question anywhere never mind on a SO site. When it comes to answering also I admit I have never been motivated by anything but what you suggest (quality) with a small exception: SO puts some pressure on reaching a certain reputation before it will even let you comment and so the first while is motivated by collecting a little reputation. That's a SO design feature I guess. I'm personally blown away at the number of lazy unresearched questions I see posted!